# Access denied when creating a new user

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having problem when I try to add a user to my database in phpMyAdmin:

```
ERROR : #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The SQL query is shown below:

```
CREATE USER 'my_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '***';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'my_database'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED BY '***' WITH
  MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0
  MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0
  MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0
  MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

I have already logged in to phpMyAdmin with root access.

Comment: it seems your roo user doesnt have the create user priviledge.Are you sure its a super user account?

Comment: Who is `roo`, is it `root`'s Australian arch-nemesis?

Comment: Sorry for my fault on typing root actually this is root not roo

Comment: @Mihai I think root user have full permission ?! isn't?

Comment: Do you run all those statements at the same time?

Comment: hmm lets i explain: i loged in to phpmyadmin in Firefox with user root and selected Users Tab then Add user and user = my_user host = localhost password = my_password and ate end Global privileges= check all then go

Comment: When i unchecked Administration privilege every things is okay !! why i have such problem ?!Why i can't use administration privilege with user root to create new user ?!

Comment: It might be that phpmyadmin is buggy,you can try http://www.heidisql.com/